# Installing Windows 7, UBuntu 12.04 and Fedora 18 (19) in triple boot with SWAP and Files space in HDD

Tags: installation, grub2, partitioning, swap, dual-boot

I'm new... but, i want you to help me...
I want a Triple-boot, Windows 7, Ubuntu 12.04 and Fedora 18.. or 19...and i found this post (question...(?)

[How do I triple-boot Ubuntu, Fedora and Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156045/how-do-i-triple-boot-ubuntu-fedora-and-windows-7)

and it is great, BUT i think it would be better if i dedicate some space to the SWAP... I have a 1TB HDD...so, here is my plan:

I want 200GB for Windows 7, another 200GB for Ubuntu 12.04, other 200GB for Fedora 18 (or 19, whichever is more stable) AND the other 400GB -pay attention- to use as my files space... i mean, use those 400GB to save my files, music, images and so i can use them in any of the 3 O.S. do you follow me?... so, when i play games in Windows i can see my photos of the last Christmas, and when i'm working on Ubuntu y can see the SAME photos of the last Christmas, and when experimenting with fedora (18 or 19 lol) i can see the SAME photos of the last Christmas.

BUT i want to tell me that if it is a good idea to give some space to the SWAP... i read in the same link ([How do I triple-boot Ubuntu, Fedora and Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156045/how-do-i-triple-boot-ubuntu-fedora-and-windows-7)) at the end that it is possible to have the SAME swap for Ubuntu and Fedora, but i don't really understand because i understood that it is convenient to have the DOUBLE SWAP space of your RAM memory, i mean, i have 4 GB of RAM, so, it is recommendable to have 8GB in SWAP...

So, are 2 things:

1 - The partition of my HDD to work fine with the 3 O.S and the space for my files.

2 – The specifications for the SWAP memory...

I want to accentuate that the space its not a problem, remember that i have a 1TB HDD, so i can give a lot to the SWAP, but i don't really know how much it is correct, maybe if i give it a lot of space it would be an error and the system(s) crash... i dunno.
So, please help me... i'm very eager to install them.. ALL THE 3 S.O.

Comment: Win7 tends to create a System Reserved partition and an OS partition.  The exact space you dedicate to each partition is your own choice, there IS no guidelines to how to partition.  The problem you're going to run into is that you're going to have space for a primary partition and then need the rest of the drive to be extended, and partitioned such that one part of the extended logical partition is for one of the LInux distros, and the rest is for Swap.

Comment: Fedora likes to default to LVM which is more complicated. Only if entire drive is LVM does it offer much advantage. Change default install to use standard ext4 / (root). Use NTFS for shared data. Swap only needs to be as large as RAM if hibernating, but if hibernating you cannot share swap. Best not to hibernate anyway.

Answer (score 0):

the 400gb partition you want use, format it as ntfs only and add mount entries of that partition in /etc/fstab of both ubuntu and fedora . assuming 400gb partition no as 5 
**/dev/sda5   /home/username/pictures   ntfs   defaults  0 0** (you can change mountpt as you want)

swap should be twice of ram if ram is less than 4gb if greater than 4gb then swap space 4gb is enough