# Can't Install Windows 8, Fedora 19 with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Need Help... :'(

Tags: grub2, fedora

I am new here, I want to *install*  **windows 8**, **Fedora 19** and **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS** on my laptop. Which is Dell Inspiron 15R 7520 SE. But whenever I install Ubuntu After Fedora, the GRUB is showing Fedora is not Installed. I'd also tried to re-install GRUB using Live CD of Ubuntu but it leads me to some Command Page. Don't know what's that. It's really very frustrating. Please Help me Friends.. I want these three on my Laptop.

I also want to know about GRUB customization but before that i want to Triple Boot my laptop.

I've tried many things to solve this issue but didn't find any perfect solution for this.

Please Help me.

:'(

[image: GRUB error]

Comment: The latest version of Fedora is [Fedora 20](http://fedoraproject.org/en/get-fedora) - it was released yesterday :-). Anyway, there is a question on this already [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/156045/how-do-i-triple-boot-ubuntu-fedora-and-windows-7).

Comment: Is it all on one hard drive?

Comment: Yes, its all on one hard drive.

Comment: Hey Wilf, I've seen that before and also tried that but that's not working for me. Unfortunately I am getting error with GRUB.

Comment: use @wilf - otherwise I won't get it :-). Please add the error that Grub gives to your question (a photo would do) - but the problem likely is that there is to many partitions for it to handle.

Comment: ok @wilf and thankx. I am new here so its little strange to work properly for me. I am adding some pics.

Comment: sorry, not able to add pics over here. help me for this first.. :( it feels bad. @wilf

Comment: Thank You @wilf for pic.. :) Now i m feeling like a fool  :( thankx 4 adding pic. I hope now you understand what's my problem.

Comment: Sorry, just trying to look up possible solutions to the problem...

Comment: yes please.. take your time.. I am also doing this. :)

Comment: Right... So, when windows is installed, install Fedora - check what it wants to partition the hard drive as, and replicate that with 'custom partitioning', allowing at least 1GB for `/boot`, placing that first, then add a `/swap` partition as well. Then check whether both Windows and Fedora work, and that you can see both in the GRUB screen. Then install Ubuntu, allowing it its own separate partitions in `Something Else` setup *(I think it prompts if anything is wrong...)*. Then hope it works :-) - and don't try boot repair in Ubuntu if Fedora does not show...

Comment: Well, First I installed Windows, then I Installed Fedora and Added 300MB for /boot and 2.5GB for swap. Yes it worked like always it does to show Windows and Fedora in Fedora's Grub. But when I install Ubuntu next to Fedora, I see only Ubuntu and Windows 8 on Ubuntu's GRUB. And if I Re-install its GRUB then I am facing this GRUB Problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to do this same install and I have never gotten it to work cleanly on one hard drive. Here is what you need to do:

1) Install Windows 8 because it will write over the MBR.
 2) Resize partitions because Windows 8 will want it all
 3) Install Fedora on the free space
 4) Repartition again if you didn't leave free space
 5) Install Ubuntu

If you do this all on one single disk you will have a ton of partitions. I think Windows 8 comes with 5 partitions including the Recovery partition. The Recovery partition can be deleted if you have a separate recovery method. Fedora will only need 2 or 3 partitions (if you want `/` and `/home` separate you will need separate partitions). Ubuntu will also need 2 or 3 partitions, but Ubuntu and Fedora can share the `/home` and `swap` partitions if you get them to play nicely (not easy). Remember that you can only have 4 partitions, with the 4th being an extended partition. I think overall you can have up to 16 partitions. When you get this many partitions, things start to get very sloppy and hard to manage. What you can do is have a partition for boot, temp and swap shared between linux systems (`/boot/` and `/tmp/`) in order to simplify things.

What I did, is on my desktop I just bought more hard drives and put each operating system on a different drive. Now on my laptop I only have room for one Hard drive so what I did is I am running Mac OSX and then running Ubuntu and Fedora in VirtualBox when I need them. They run really good in VirtualBox.

Installing 3 operating systems on one hard drive will be a huge process and it might save you a lot of pain to consider alternate solutions.

Comment: One note - merging Ubuntu and Fedora home directories does not always work, due to conflicting configuration files...

Comment: Thankx John, I didn't install these three yet on my Hard Drive. But yes I want to. That's why I am trying to solve this on my VMware. But that's showing me these problems. And yes, this process makes lots of partitions. In my case it made 9. But it's ok.. help me to install these all in one hard drive. I've seen many pics over internet of Multiple boot. I also want my Lappy like that. ;)

Comment: Ok, use VMWare on your laptop to emulate Ubuntu and Fedora (I am assuming your laptop is runnning Windows 8 or Mac OSX) and then on your desktop buy an extra hard drive or two. I recommend letting Windows 8 have it's own hard drive because it is pretty picky.

Comment: No no, right now I am working on Windows 7 & 8. But I want Windows 8, Fedora and Ubuntu. thankx for the help @John

Comment: So on your Windows 7 or 8 laptop just install VMWare and then you can emulate Fedora and Ubuntu. I have tried it, they run really well.