# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 on top of Luna

Tags: grub2, system-installation

I currently have elementaryOS Luna dual-booted with Windows 8.1. My grub version is `grub-install (GRUB) 1.99-21ubuntu3.19`. I plan to install `Ubuntu 16.04` on top of this and want to know the steps to do so such that my previous environment stays intact. Any gotchas and pitfalls will also be helpful

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Do you want Windows, elementaryOS AND Ubuntu? The tab refers to dual-boot. Do you want to triple-boot? Have you seen e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/156045/how-do-i-triple-boot-ubuntu-fedora-and-windows-7

Comment: @arochester yes I want to triple boot, sorry about the tag, couldn't find triple boot tag. Should I remove the tag?

Comment: I knows about how to partition my drives and all that jazz. I just need to know if i go ahead and install Ubuntu in a different partition And the grub that Ubuntu 16 comes with will discover my previously installed systems?

Comment: In my experience, Grub finds all OSes including Windows. If you haven't planned it, I might suggest that you create a separate partition for /home for your Ubuntu install.  It may come in handy later for upgrades and other troubleshooting and repairs.